# START_STICKY for Activity that behaves like a Service

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

If we want an Activity to behave like a Service, We can move it to the background using:

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
```

and we can hide it from the Recents screen using:

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

But how we make it START_STICKY to re-create automatically after it is killed?

Comment: This makes no sense. An `Activity` is a completely different thing from a `Service`. Why would you want to use an `Activity` as a `Service`? An `Activity` (generally) has UI (Views) and is part of a task which is part of the whole user interface. A `Service` is a component that performs background processing. It has no UI.

Comment: @DavidWasser I know all this, I want to do it for learning purpose, It's just a challenge that I want to solve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't automatically recreate an `Activity` after it is killed.  That would be creating a denial-of-service attack on the user's device, by continuously relaunching the `Activity` in front of them and preventing them from doing anything else.  Unless you were thinking that it wouldn't launch/show any UI, and just run in the created-but-not-started state, in which case there's no way to do that either, because that's what a `Service` is for—`Activity`s are for showing UI.

Short version: if you want these service-like behaviors, you should use a `Service` and just access the `Service` from your `Activity`.